# How to update state by useEffect in React?

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, use-state, factory-pattern, i18next

I'm newbie in React. I try to make a project with price calculator which is prepared in 2 languages. Everything is based on Factory Pattern. To change language I used i18next framework.Static text elements on website change dynamically and everything works fine.Problem is when I try change to another language object *logo.text* stay the same. I know that useState render once so how can i use useEffect? or is another solution to solve render problem ?  I put few elements to calculate in array of objects in useState. Looks something like this:

```
  const [logo, setLogo] = useState([
{
  type: "tocheck",
  checked: false,
  name: "rights",
  text: t("rightsLogo.text"),
  price: 200,
},])
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to have a `language` state or prop and you need to call `useEffect` with `language` in the dependency array and update the `logo` state using `setLogo` inside the `useEffect`.

```
useEffect(() => {
    setLogo({
        //your logo object here
    })
}, [language])
```

Comment: pass t in the dependency array

Answer (score 0):

You can just try out use effect to render it by putting `logo` as dependency variable something like this:

```
useEffect = ({},[logo])
```

What above basically does is whenever the state of logo changes it re renders it.

You would also need to actually use `setState` for the logo state to change

Answer (score 0):

Try this , it might solve your problem

```
 useEffect(() => {
   // thing you want to update
}, [JSON.stringi(logo)])
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).